# Singe data from mongodb not showing

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to get single products data from mongodb in reactjs but when I am mapping that data its not mapping and giving this error:

[image]

this is my backend way of getting single prod:

```
const getProdsById = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const prod = await Prod.findById(req.params.id);
  if (prod) {
    res.json(prod);
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("Product not found");
  }
});
```

this is the routes page:

```
const {
  getProds,
  getProdsById,
  postProds,
  updateProds,
  delProds,
} = require("../controllers/ProdControllers");

router.route("/").get(getProds).post(postProds);
router.route("/:id").delete(delProds).put(updateProds).get(getProdsById);
```

i tested this by using postman and it worked there easily but in the react part its not working and giving error!

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

product collection model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const prodScheme = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    pname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    longname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    shortname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    specs: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    discount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    netprice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    ratings: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
    brand: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
    banner: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Prod", prodScheme);
```

my react frontend:

```
  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const [Prods, setProds] = useState([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const presponse = await fetch(`/api/prods/${searchParams.get("id")}`);
      const pjson = await presponse.json();
      if (presponse.ok) {
        setProds(pjson);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // console.error(err);
      // alert(err.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [Prods]);

{Prods.map((prod) => (
   <h2>{prod.pname}</h2>
))}
```

btw `searchParams` is working fine i can see the exact id in url box aswell and also i printed it in console then also tested it with postman and it works fine

Comment: Console log the pjson to check if it's coming or not

Comment: its not working aswell